# Fastest way to calculate distance between all rows in a dense eigen::matrix

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between every pair of rows in a 1000x1000 matrix using Eigen. What I have so far is something along these lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows(); ++i){
    VectorXd refRow = matrix.row(i);
    for (int j = i+1; j < matrix.rows(); ++j){
        VectorXd eleRow = matrix.row(j);            
        euclid_distance = (refRow - eleRow).lpNorm<2>();
        ...
    }
}
```

My code includes other code here replaced with "..." but for testing the performance I have removed it.

Now I don't expect this to run at the speed of light but it is taking a lot more than I expected. Am I doing something wrong in using C++ \ the Eigen library that might be slowing this down?
Is there any other preferred method?

Comment: Do you have the ability to specify the [storage order](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) of the matrix? It may behoove you from a cache-efficiency standpoint to use a row-major ordering, which is not the default.

Comment: I actually just found about that myself and tried to switch it, still waiting on the timing results to compare but it still takes a **long** time

Comment: You're making copies of the rows as you go through the matrix; don't do that. Use the `.row()` values explicitly; Eigen's expression template engine should implement that efficiently (i.e. it will reference the values in the already-existing matrix instead of copying them). Example: `euclid_distance = (matrix.row(i) - matrix.row(j)).lpNorm<2>();`

Comment: Also, I would define a **long** time. Are you building with optimization enabled?

Comment: Well running on VS2013 in default Release mode settings, it took 4.5 minutes for a 1000x1000 matrix, am I expected too much (I know it should take a while)?

Comment: Well it seems this might be VS acting up but I'll look into it. Is there anything you can see besides that? Thank you all for your tips so far.

Comment: Sounds like you've got something else going on. I built a small self-contained example using your code above, built using `gcc` with `-O3` optimization on Ubuntu 13.04, and it runs in 3.3 sec on my Core-i7 Sandy Bridge machine.